Logger with ostream functionality for threaded program
I would like to implement a thread safe logger where every part of the project has it's own logger. The logger should be able to handle 'operator<<' like std::ostream and should only propagate strings to the global logger when a line is written. The global logger shall then prepend the string and write it to std::cout and/or std::ofstream depending on setup.
I have to issues with the code I came up with so far.

The way I check for complete strings and how I pass them to the global class feels really suboptimal
When I run the proposed code it seems like one logger outraces the other one although I start them simultaneously

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class GlobalLogger
{
public:
    GlobalLogger() : m_prefix("Prefix | ") {};

    friend class Logger;

private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::string m_prefix;

    void log(std::string str)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        std::cout << m_prefix << str << std::endl;
    }
};

class Logger
{
public:
    Logger(std::shared_ptr<GlobalLogger> gLog, std::string name) : m_sb(), m_os(&m_sb), m_name(name), m_gLog(gLog) {}

    template<class T>
    friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& log, const T& output);

    friend Logger& operator<<(Logger &log, std::ostream & (*manip)(std::ostream &));

private:
    std::ostream m_os;
    std::stringbuf m_sb;
    const std::string m_name;
    std::shared_ptr<GlobalLogger> m_gLog;

    void extractLine()
    {
        std::string str = m_sb.str();
        size_t pos = str.find_first_of('\n');
        
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            m_gLog->log(m_name + " | " + str.substr(0,pos));
            m_sb.str(str.substr(pos+1));
        }
    }
};

template<class T>
Logger& operator<<(Logger& log, const T& output)
{
    log.m_os << output;
    log.extractLine();
    return log;
}

Logger& operator<<(Logger &log, std::ostream & (*manip)(std::ostream &))
{
    manip(log.m_os);
    log.extractLine();
    return log;
}

void threadFcn(Logger *log, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start)
{
    int counter = 0;

    std::this_thread::sleep_until(start);
    
    while (counter < 10)
    {   
        *log << "Counter: " << counter << "\n";
        counter++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<GlobalLogger> gLog = std::make_shared<GlobalLogger>();
    Logger log1(gLog, "Logger1");
    Logger log2(gLog, "Logger2");

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);
    
    std::thread th1(threadFcn, &log1, start);
    std::thread th2(threadFcn, &log2, start);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    
    return 0;
}

